# Concise points: how to offer extra information

Tags: usability, lists

A friend of mine [made a site](https://sites.google.com/view/catbell/dos/interactie) which lists pointers for teachers at regular schools who have one or more deaf children in their class. These are clear, concise, one-sentence "Do's" with regard to teaching a deaf child.

How could extra info be added to some of these points without cluttering, without breaking the clarity and  brevity?

With extra info i mean a short paragraph of extra explanation, maybe some links. Not all the points would need this, but i think some points could do with a more in-depth explanation, examples or links to further reading.

Comment: Can you show/tell us what ideas you have to solve this problem. As of now, this question just asks us to do the designing for you.

Answer (score 2):

The aim of any website should be to provide people with a quick access to information, without having to waste time looking for it. Basically it implies that any website must employ **scannable text**.

There is a brilliant article that may help your friend with respect to this -

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/legibility-readability-comprehension/

> Basically, what the article says is that Users won’t read web content unless the text is clear, the words and sentences are simple, and the information is easy to understand

To organise the bullet points, your friend can use something called as 'Chunking'. 
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chunking/

> Chunking is a concept that originates from the field of cognitive psychology. UX professionals can break their text and multimedia content into smaller chunks to help users process, understand, and remember it better.

I suggest that make the content legible and easy to scan and that can be by chunking the text. Make each bullet point as a chunk and leave enough whitespace around each chunk. You can play with typography heirarchy and experiement with the bolder fonts for the main pointers and smaller/lighter fonts for the extra 'paragraph' text. One idea I can suggest is as below -

[image]

Comment: I had something like this in mind but with the grey tekst visible after clicking (like in the faq here: https://www.hollandsnieuwe.nl/klantenservice#!) but then the whole thing moves too much for my taste.

Comment: @Ivana I agree, I'm not a fan of collapsible panels myself. It feels quite clunky